# How to stop app from crashing when device font scale changes?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, crash, font-scaling

I'm new to React Native and I've been trying to prevent my app from crashing when the system font scaling increases. I've looked at various answers on different platforms, but I haven't found the right solution yet. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

`"react-native": "^0.67.5",`

I've tried using `android:configChanges="fontScale"` as suggested in some stack answers, which does prevent the app from crashing. However, the React Native app itself doesn't adapt to the font scale size of the device.

Answer (score 0):

I will try this in AndroidManifest.xml file.

<activity

...

android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|fontScale"

...
android:launchMode="singleTask"

> 

....

This is working for me.